# How to implement a sidebar which does not open a new side per click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I want to have a sidebar which should open a new view, but I don't want a new page to open.
My sidebar is always the same and I don't want to copy it to all other pages. [If you want an example click on this photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYKaf.png)

So I don't want to change the site the user is right now, I only want to have another content or other functions you can do on this site.

If it is possible (and how), please write me

Thanks

Comment: You want to integrate a sidebar to your website which can be open or close without reloading the page. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a small working demo of a JS sidebar, you can add some nice css effect like animation and better styling on list items. Hope it helps.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sidebar demo</title>
  <style>
 #sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
 }
 
 #sidebar.active {
  left: 0px;
 }
 
 #sidebar ul li {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  lis-style: none;
 }
 
 .hamburger-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top: 20px;
 }
 
 .hamburger-btn span {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
 }
 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar" class="active">
  <div class="hamburger-btn" onclick="togglesidebar()">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div id="content">
  
 </div>
 <script>
  function togglesidebar() {
  
   document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
  
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the work, but that wa not my question :)

Comment: what was your question then?